# #1064 - SQL syntax Error while trying to import

Tags: mysql, import, mariadb, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `migration_versions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `migration_versions` (
  `version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

is giving me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */' at line 5

**Update:**

This is the original exported statement. The only thing I did was change collations to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `migration_versions`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `migration_versions` (
  `version` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: What is that `SET` statement supposed to be doing here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated post with the full statement, rather than just the one shown in the error. Also added some more info.

Comment: I wonder why the server doesn't return an charset/collation error since you can't use a utf8mb4 collation with utf8(mb3) character set.